# Problema com resultado de cálculo maior que Int64

Tags: c#, .net, matemática

Estou fazendo o expoente de um número e preciso que o resultado saia num formato específico, no entanto não sei como fazer, segue o código:

```
double num1 = 290287121823;
double num2 = 538783;
double resultado = Math.Pow(num1, 2) + num2;
```

Meu código esta trazendo 8.42666130962812E+22 mas o que preciso é 84266613096281243382112. Como faço isso? Tentei formatos com `.ToString()` e forçar a conversão para `BigInteger` do `System.Numerics` mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução realmente é usar o [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0). Eu usei e deu certo, mas fiz o processo todo com ele. Se a fonte de dados era o `double`, converta imediatamente cada parte antes de fazer as operações. Nem precisei de formatação.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bKW4ya). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3sUbh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/BigInteger.cs). Com opções de formatação, ainda que este não seja o problema.

[Outras opções de formatação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Mais informações](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Ola bigow, fiz um teste mas é como se ele apenas adicionasse os zeros no final e perdesse algo nessa conversão. O BigInteger tinha me gerado algo semelhante também mas ainda não consegui o ponto certo. Quando o número é menor que Int64 funciona de boa mas quando extrapola e tenho q usar Double ai algo se perde.

Comment: vou testar outras possibilidades pelo link que enviou. vlw

Comment: Opa, então vou testar o trecho anterior ja fazendo com o BigInteger, tava usando ele só no final após o cálculo. Retorno já

Comment: Funcionou bigow!! Você é o cara! O problema também é que não considerei usar o BigInteger.Pow ai estava usando o BigInteger apenas após o resultado do Math.Pow, vi seu código lá e resolveu o problema.Obrigado